# Show that H is a subset of the normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My Abstract Algebra professer assigned us this homework problem which I'm assuming he created himself:

> Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Show that $H$ is a subset of the normalizer of $H$.

The normalizer of $H$ is defined as $N(H)=\{x \in G: x^{-1}Hx=H\}$. I've spent more time than I'd like trying just to understand the logic behind the statement and I end up confusing myself. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just trying to a grasp on what others are replying with.

Comment: @MetinY.: ????????

Answer (score 4):

Let $x \in H$. We need to show $x^{-1}Hx = H$. Suppose $h\in H$, and consider $x^{-1}hx \in x^{-1}Hx$. Since $x \in H$, we have $x^{-1} \in H$, and so $x^{-1}hx \in H$. Hence, $x^{-1}Hx\subseteq H$ for $x\in H$. Now suppose $h \in H$ and consider $k := xhx^{-1}\in H$. Then, we have $x^{-1}kx = h \in x^{-1}Hx$. Hence, $H\subseteq x^{-1}Hx$, and so $x^{-1}Hx = H$. Hence, $x \in N(H)$.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense! One more question. Do we arrive at x^-1hx is an element of H since the products of each would still be within H?

Comment: @user80320 Yes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $h, x \in H$. Can you find $k\in H$ such that $x^{-1} k x =h$? Also, is it possible that for some $m\in H$ you have $x^{-1} k x \not \in H$? 
Can you see why this answers the question?

Comment: The only _k_ I can think of that satisfies this is the identity _e_.

Comment: To clarify, for each h and x in H, you only need to be able to find one specific k in H for that pair. Each h,x pair can have a different k.

Comment: Recall that $x^{-1} H x = H$ means that when I look at the elements $x^{-1} k x$ for $k \in H$ I can get *any* element $h \in H$ and also all of the elements $x^{-1} k x$ are in $H$.

Comment: Thank you so much. i appreciate your input!

Comment: You're welcome.